# Use Reverse Proxy from Https client to Http server running locally on my machine

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, https, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a published site that uses HTTPS. The site needs to communicates with a HTTP node Express API. The API is run on my local machine. Everything worked fine until I switched the client application to use HTTPS. Now I receive mixed content warnings. I have been reading about reverse proxys and wonder if this could be the solution to my problem. Is it possible to proxy a request to my localhost? Or will localhost point to the server the proxy is on?

I have been looking at using nginx as the reverse proxy server but I have zero experience with proxys and not positive how to go about it.

I am mainly wondering if it is possible or not before I dig any deeper.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a pretty standard use case for using nginx (or any other reverse proxy). You would configure the location prefixes, etc that need to go to your backend application and proxy (via [proxy_pass](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) directive) to them. Any static content can be served directly from nginx. All of this can then behind nginx.

Assuming that your application is never issuing absolute urls which make use of "http://" this should resolve your mixed content warnings.

You will probably want to read some tutorials but the basics of your configuration would be:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl; # you can also add http2
    server_name hostnames that you listen for;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/cert.key;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/cert.pem;

    root /var/www/sites/foo.com;

    location /path/handled/by/application {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000; # or whatever port is
    }

}
```